# Error al generar consulta en datatable con linq y backgroundworker

Tags: c#

Estoy utilizando el componente BackgroundWorker para generar una tarea en segundo plano, lo que hago es recorrer un datatable y ejecuto una busqueda en un segundo datatable para verificar si el dato a comparar existe, de ser así, entonces ejecuta un store procedure.

El problema que tengo es que al momento de hacer la consulta en el datatable utilizando linq sale del backgroundWorker y no realiza la tarea, quiero saber como corregir esta situación.

```
Archivo archivo = new Archivo();

        dta = (DataTable)dgvRegistros.DataSource;
        dta1 = (DataTable)dgvProcesado.DataSource;

        int progreso = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dta.Rows)
        {
            var dato = dta1.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<string>("Referencia") == row["Transaccion"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

            if (dato == null)
            {
                archivo.GuardarDeposito(idcuenta, row["Descripcion"].ToString(), double.Parse(row["Monto"].ToString()),
                    row["Referencia"].ToString());                    
            }               

            progreso++;
            backgroundWorker3.ReportProgress(progreso);
        }
```

Comment: que quiere decir sale? hay algun error?

Comment: Has comprobado que `dta` tenga filas?

Comment: @gbianchi no sale ningún error, solo que sale del evento y no ejecuta nada, ni siquiera llega al if

Comment: @Pikoh lo he comprobado y trae filas.

Comment: el codigo parece estar bien, y decis que no sale nada? entonces no tenes datos.. no hay mucho que podamos ayudarte asi como esta la pregunta. hay datos en esos datasource?

Comment: @gbianchi si trae datos, ya lo he verificado.

Comment: entonces etnra al for.. y que hace la linea siguiente? lo seguiste paso a paso? una funcion no se corta asi porque si. O lanza una excepcion, o hace lo que tiene que hacer...

Comment: @gbianchi Verifiqué paso a paso que hace y lo que pude ver es que al momento de hacer la consulta con Linq ahí se interrumpe la función sin lanzar ninguna excepción.

Comment: sip.. la funcion no se interrumpe. fijate que no este dentro de un try, o algo que esta evitando que veas porque se corta la funcion. si sale sin hacer nada, es porque hay un error. No se puede cortar una funcion al medio

Comment: `referencia` es de tipo `string`? De todas maneras, parece extraño que no lance la excepción...

Comment: puede tenerlas bloqueadas por un proceso superior.. o no estar depurando con excepciones...

Comment: @gbianchi si, en algun lado se estará tragando la excepción...

Comment: Debugeaste la instrucción `Linq`? utiliza `F11` para que puedas verlo con mas detalle.

Comment: Acabo de hacer un debug paso a paso, y ya di con el problema, es el nombre de las columnas del datatable las tengo con un nombre y en la llamada la nombro de otro, de todas maneras gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: @RamónZoquier por favor **[publica y acepta tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**. Los comentarios son temporales. Saludos.